# How to free memory in Tensorflow C api

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, tensorflow2.0, valgrind

I was learning how to use the Tensorflow C api and I had trouble freeing memory. According to Valgrind, I lost 112 bytes in 1 block. I don't know what I missed. I believe it's a type casting issue but I could be wrong.

This is the valgrind message

```
==60261==    by 0x5958E1A: TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel (in /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.so.2.11.0)
==60261==    by 0x10A136: CreateModel (in /home/murage/Desktop/06/main)
==60261== 
==60261== LEAK SUMMARY:
==60261==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60261==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60261==      possibly lost: 636,088 bytes in 16,611 blocks
==60261==    still reachable: 13,565,248 bytes in 208,524 blocks
==60261==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==60261==                         newarray           : 13,448 bytes in 11 blocks
==60261==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==60261== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

Could anyone show me what I failed to free and how I should free it? Also, if there are unnecessary type casts please let me know

```
typedef struct train *Model;
struct train 
{
    const char *modelDirectory;
    const char *tags;
    
    TF_Graph *graph;
    TF_Status *status;
    TF_SessionOptions *sessionOptions; 
    TF_Buffer *runOptions;
    TF_Session *session; 
    
    TF_Output *input;
    TF_Output *output;
    
    int numberOfInputs;
    int numberOfOutputs;
    
    TF_Tensor **inputValues;
    TF_Tensor **outputValues;
    
    float *data;
    int dataLength;
};

Model CreateModel(const char *modelDirectory, const char *tags, char *inputLayerName, char *outputLayerName, int dataLength)
{
    Model model = malloc(sizeof(*model));
    int numberOfTags = 1;
    model->numberOfInputs = 1;
    model->numberOfOutputs = 1;
    model->modelDirectory = modelDirectory;
    model->tags = tags;
    
    model->graph = TF_NewGraph();
    model->status = TF_NewStatus();
    model->sessionOptions = TF_NewSessionOptions();
    model->runOptions = NULL;
    model->session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(model->sessionOptions, model->runOptions, model->modelDirectory, &model->tags, numberOfTags, model->graph, NULL, model->status);
    
    assert(TF_GetCode(model->status) == TF_OK);
    
    model->input  = (TF_Output*)malloc(sizeof(TF_Output) * model->numberOfInputs);
    model->output = (TF_Output*)malloc(sizeof(TF_Output) * model->numberOfOutputs);
    
    TF_Output inputLayer  = {TF_GraphOperationByName(model->graph, inputLayerName), 0};
    TF_Output outputLayer = {TF_GraphOperationByName(model->graph, outputLayerName), 0};
    
    assert(outputLayer.oper != NULL);
    assert(inputLayer.oper  != NULL);
    
    model->input[0]  = inputLayer;
    model->output[0] = outputLayer;
    
    model->inputValues  = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*)*model->numberOfInputs);
    model->outputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*)*model->numberOfOutputs);
    
    model->data = calloc(dataLength, sizeof(float));
    model->dataLength = dataLength;
    return model;
}

//Destroy Model
void DestroyModel(Model model)
{
    TF_DeleteSessionOptions(model->sessionOptions);
    TF_DeleteSession(model->session, model->status);
    TF_DeleteStatus(model->status);
    TF_DeleteGraph(model->graph);
    TF_DeleteBuffer(model->runOptions);
    free(model->input);
    free(model->output);
    free(model->inputValues);
    free(model->outputValues);
    free(model->data);
    free(model);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Valigrind provide a bit more details? Please show complete message. Copy&paste as formatted text into your question.

Comment: In C you don't need (and should not) cast the return value of `malloc` and similar functions.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for the response. I added the Valgrind message